# Dockerized Asp.net core 2.1 - Hangfire not starting

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, hangfire, asp.net-core-2.1

Situation:
Use Hangfire with Asp.net core 2.1 and Docker.

- App crashes on docker run. When I comment all codes related to
  Hangfire, app works perfectly.
- If I run the app via IIS express on Visual Studio, app works fine
  with Hangfire.

Issue:

```
Application startup exception: System.Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started. ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.ThrowIfNotConfigured(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Hangfire.HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IApplicationBuilder app, BackgroundJobServerOptions options, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, JobStorage storage)
```

[error on docker run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwzFm.png)

Connection strings on appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"TestDB": "Server=[server_instance]\\LOCALHOST;database=[db1];uid=[user];pwd=[pwd]",
"HangfireDB": "Server=[server_instance]\\LOCALHOST;database=Hangfire;uid=[user];pwd=[pwd]"
  },
```

Any idea guys why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running you database in the same container as the app? If not, the apps must belong to the same network in order to communicate with each other, if your database is dockerized too. Be aware that by default you can't connect from a docker guest to the docker host (in case your db is running on the docker host). Please provide more information about your setup

Comment: @Tseng, yes you're right. My db is running on docker host. That's why it's not working.

Is there any way I can access db? Suppose on production AWS, my app runs on an ECS container whereas my db is on an EC2, how the ECS instance will be able to connect to the EC2?

Comment: Its not recommended for docker containers to connect to the host directly (though it can be enabled by adding the "host" network to the container. If your database is outside of the host, and normally reachable via public (or internal IP) it should be no problem. So if your db is directly hosted in AWS then you should use its ip and connection string to connect. For local development you should put your database inside a container to and put both container in the same network (i.e. using docker compose or similar)

Comment: @Tseng, thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the server values in your connection strings from LOCALHOST to be your ip